# how to filter records for previous year in odoo?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I was trying with the following code which i got from odoo related website

```
<filter icon="terp-go-month" string="Last Year"
                         domain="[('date_from','&lt;=', (context_today()-relativedelta(day=31,months=12,years=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
                         ('date_from','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(day=1,months=1,years=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"
                         help="last year"/>
```

nothing seems to work though.
Anyone with any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of previous year:

```
<filter string="Prev Month" name="prev_month" 
    domain="[('data','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-01')),('data','&lt;',time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-01'))]"
/>
```

Comment: OthmaneFARAJ, thank you first of all, i am trying to first filter previous year records and then i wanted to filter month wise, like                        <filter string="Dec" name="dec" domain="[('fdate','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')),('fdate','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-12-01'))]"/> but the records wont show up accordingly when i click first previous year and then specific month

Comment: @ShravyaShetty , you welcome, i think this second exemple can help you more`<filter string="Filter by month" domain="[(fdate.strftime('%%m')','=','December')]"/>` , please if my answer about the previous year works to you check like correct to help other people.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Failed to evaluate search criterions: 
{"code":400,"message":"Evaluation Error","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug

Comment: Error in the search  operation, send me your code to verify what happend @ShravyaShetty

Comment: Error","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug":"Local evaluation failure\nExpected \")\", got \"(string)\"\n\n{\"domains\":[[[\"state\",\"!=\",\"draft\"]],\"[(fdate.strftime('%m')','=','12')]\"],\"contexts\":[{\"lang\":\"en_US\",\"tz\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"uid\":1}],\"group_by_seq\":[]}"}}